# How to restore deleted orders in Bigcommerce?

Tags: api, restore, bigcommerce, orders

My API programmer has deleted all the orders in our bigcommerce account by accident

He entered this -
https://botanicalcraft.com/api/v2/orders/

Instead of this -
https://botanicalcraft.com/api/v2/orders/1969

How can we restore the orders to our account? I do not see the orders in archive or deleted within the Bigcommerce admin.

This happened at 10/7/2014 at 1:00pm PST

Comment: If you didn't make a backup first, I recommend paying Bigcommerce to restore.